# Beginner RC circuit question

Tags: capacitor, resistors, circuit-analysis

First of all, sorry to ask such a simple and uninteresting question, but I'm a very beginner into electrical engineering.

I have got an exercise to do, with a simple RC circuit, where I need to determine some voltages at given times. The following image is the exercise (where E is a low frequencies generator) and the values I found:

[image]

Even if I applied what I thought to be the good techniques, my circuit is equivalent at t=0 and t=oo . So Uc is the same.

Did I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At t=0 the capacitor is a short circuit, therefore the voltage across and the current through the parallel resistor must be 0.

Comment: So I have only E and a resistor left then? I thought that when a branch was empty I could remove it safely.

Answer (score 0):

At t=0 :
since the capacitor behaves as short circuit, the resistor 'R' will be removed as it is short circuited.

Only a resistor (the resistor at top) will be remaining in the circuit apart from the source!
so condition at t=0 and t=infinite are diffrent!